# Magento, add some text beside item title

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am new to Magento but willing to learn. :)

For the current project we need to add the Serial number next to the purchased item. Serial should be added in the invoice (PDF and html). It doesn't need to be new field, it is enough to add it next to the item name, or under it.
I have the serial number already saved in the DB, so the only thing I need is to find the html file to modify and there call the SQL statement to get the serial.

Please I could really use any help where to locate that file and what to change.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `template/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/default.phtml` for frontend display

The template folder can be either in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/` or in the package/theme folder of your store.

For backend display use  `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/view/items/renderer/` folder, which contains two template files: `configurable.phtml` for configurable type products, and `default.phtml`, for other types